# Firebase server authentication on localhost without private credentials / api secrets

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, jwt

I have an open source web app that is using Firebase for authentication. The front end doesn't need private keys or credentials to create users and interface with Firebase - all it needs is a config containing the public key and project name etc. The front end then sends the JWT tokens in the header of all requests to the back end... However in the back end (Spring/Java) it appears there is no way to verify these JWT tokens in without using the Firebase Admin SDK - which requires the project's private credentials.

Issue is I don't want to have to commit the private credential file to a public repository. How can I set up a development environment locally that can verify these JWT tokens in the back end server code (Java) without giving the whole world my private project credentials? Since the project is open source, I need people to be able to develop without having keys to the kingdom.

Comment: I don't see how bundling service account credentials with your back end results in public sharing.  Certainly you can build a release process that keeps the credentials safe on your server.

Comment: @DougStevenson its not the bundling it with the back end that results in sharing it. Its the fact that my app is open source - and currently I am unsure how I can set up a local development environment for contributors that does not also require me giving them the secret credentials. How can they locally develop the back end without those credentials? I'm aware I can keep it secure on the server itself.

Comment: You can simply refuse to check in the file with your credentials.  Use .gitignore or equivalent for that.  Make sure there are instructions that help people understand that they need to provide their own creds.

Comment: Well I have already added it to gitignore. I was just hoping there was a way to develop this on local host without having to set up their own projects on firebase just for testing since that’s a bit of a barrier to getting people started.

Comment: It's the standard case.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to restrict a key to permissions that only allowed access to the auth component of firebase then but my understanding is for someone to be able to use the admin sdk at all then they will need full project editor permissions.